# WCF service - initialization issue

Tags: c#, wcf, initialization

I am currently trying to create a WCF service and then host it from a commandLine application. During hosting of the service am trying to initialize it with an instance of an object called MyProxy. All calls to the service should delegate to MyProxy.

I have created a service and made calls. But I am not able to initialize the MyProxy instance in the service. It is always null. So when any calls to the service is made, I am not able to delegate it to the proxy.

I have been trying to get this work since last two days. Am lost now, not sure what is happening. Kindly help.

```
public class MasOperationsService : IMasOperations
{
    //This MyProxy instance should be used to delegate all calls to service.
    public MyProxy myProxyInstance;

    public MasOperationsService()
    {
        myProxyInstance = null;
    }
    public MasOperationsService(MyProxy proxy)
    {
        myProxyInstance = proxy;
    }

    public CoAuthorSearchResult ExtractCoAuthorsFromAuthor(long authorCellId, uint levelsToExtract)
    {
        //The service will delegate the call to MyProxy.
        //myProxyInstance is always null

        return myProxyInstance.GetProxyData(...);
    }
}

public class MyInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider
{
    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
    {
        MyProxy name = message.Headers.GetHeader<MyProxy>("Name", "http://my.namespace");
        if (name != null)
        {
            return new MasOperationsService(name);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return new MasOperationsService(null);
    }
    public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
    {
    }
}

public class MyServiceBehavior : IServiceBehavior
{
    MyInstanceProvider myProvider = new MyInstanceProvider();
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) { }
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher cd in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher ed in cd.Endpoints)
            {
                ed.DispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = this.myProvider;
            }
        }
    }
    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase) { }
}
```

The service is launched using,

```
class MyServiceLauncher
{
    ServiceHost host;
    IMasOperations proxy;
    ChannelFactory<IMasOperations> factory;

    public void StartService(MyProxy proxyInstance)
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://localhost:8730/Design_Time_Addresses/MASService/Service1";
        host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MasOperationsService), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMasOperations), GetBinding(), "");
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new MyServiceBehavior());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        factory = new ChannelFactory<IMasOperations>(GetBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

        using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)proxy))
        {
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Name", "http://my.namespace", proxyInstance));
        }
    }

    public void ShutDownService()
    {
        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();
        host.Close();
    }

    static Binding GetBinding()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding result = new BasicHttpBinding();
        return result;
    }
}
```

I also put a Debugger.Launch() almost everywhere, just to see it being initialized (Both constructor of Service and in IInstanceProvider). It dosent get fired.

Comment: Can you provide a piece of code where you're calling `GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)` method of `MyInstanceProvider` class. Also, providing contract definitions would be good.

Comment: I pasted your code into Visual Studio and I can't do anything with it because it doesn't compile (MyProxy and other types are not defined). You are asking for help to debug something. If you make it easy for me to do a debug session I will. Otherwise you probably won't get an answer.

Comment: @kobac -- I am not sure how and why I need to do this. Currently I just create an object of the service class - MasOperationsClient at the client and call the method ExtractCoAuthorsFromAuthor().

Comment: @ErnieL -- I have replied to my post with the missing types which I had missed out earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the missing types. Also in the service, there is a call 
    return myProxyInstance.GetProxyData(...);
removing the dots compiles the application.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMasOperations
{
    [OperationContract]
    CoAuthorSearchResult ExtractCoAuthorsFromAuthor(long AuthorCellId, uint LevelsToExtract);
}

public class CoAuthorSearchResult
{ }

public class MyProxy
{ 
    public CoAuthorSearchResult GetProxyData()
    {
        return new CoAuthorSearchResult();
    }
}
```

@kobac
asked for a piece of code showing where GetInstance is being called. I am not sure how and why I need to do this.

Currently I just create an object of the service class - MasOperationsClient at the client and call the method ExtractCoAuthorsFromAuthor().